# Code improvement help - for SPList creation using code

Tags: list, development

Hi Just wanted to get some tips on SharePoint List created with the following code?

I created a helper method (UpdateDisplayName())to update the display name of the columns created is there anything wrong with passing the SPList by ref? I know this implies that you can alter the list.

But I thought it would be "faster" by reference since it's object type.

If anyone can suggest a better way of doing this, I would love to know?

Thanks.

```
   private void btnCreateProductList_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(siteUrl))
            {
                SPWeb web = siteCollection.RootWeb;
                Guid listId = web.Lists.Add("Products", "A list of products", SPListTemplateType.GenericList);
                SPList list = web.Lists[listId];
                list.OnQuickLaunch = true;
                list.Update();


                // Modify display name of the Title field.
                SPField titleField = list.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName("Title");
                titleField.Title = "Category";
                titleField.Update();

                // add custom fields.
                var productDescription = list.Fields.Add("ProductDescription", SPFieldType.Note, false);
                var inventoryLevel = list.Fields.Add("InventoryLevel", SPFieldType.Integer, true);
                var listPrice = list.Fields.Add("ListPrice", SPFieldType.Currency, true);


                UpdateDisplayName(ref list, productDescription, "Product Description");
                UpdateDisplayName(ref list, inventoryLevel, "Inventory Level");
                UpdateDisplayName(ref list, listPrice, "List Price");

                SPView defaultView = list.DefaultView;
                defaultView.ViewFields.Add(productDescription);
                defaultView.ViewFields.Add(inventoryLevel);
                defaultView.ViewFields.Add(listPrice);
                defaultView.Update();

                lstResults.Items.Add("Products list created");
            }
        }

        private void UpdateDisplayName(ref SPList myList,string fieldName, string newName)
        {
            SPField field = myList.Fields.GetFieldByInternalName(fieldName);
            field.Title = newName;
            field.Update();
        }
```

Comment: Looks ok to me. You could try running http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/SPDisposeCheck to check for possible memleaks. As for performance, don't think that will matter much. But if you want to be sure; use counters to check things like execution time and memory usage.

Answer (score 2):

I'd remove the ref if there is any difference in performance (which I doubt will be measurable) then the version with ref will be the slowest.

Whenever you pass a reference type (like SPList) to a function in .Net you pass it by reference. When you specify ref in front of it you're passing a reference to the reference to the function, the only reason to pass myList as a reference is if your function wants to be able to point the reference to the reference type to point to another object.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't aware SPList by default was passed by reference in .NET.